# php in css doesn't work

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to use php inside my css but server return php-code as is `<style>p{background: url(<?php echo hello;?>)};</style>`

I see `url(<?php echo hello;?>)` in my inline style with browser console. It doesn't matter do I place `text/css` header inside the code or not, quoted or double-quoted the php section.

But this style work properly on another server. Maybe there is any setting that doesn't allow use php this way?

Comment: Where are you adding this code?

Comment: It will works fine in file by extension `.php`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the problem is that you're trying to put php code into a .css file and your server is not configured to run php from this file type.

If you're using Apache, you can try to add this line into your .htaccess file (create one in the root if you don't have it)

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .css
```

However, note that this action may cause some security issues.

Comment: It will also slow the server down, since it will now look for php code in all css files. The solution I'd prefer is the other way around - I'd stick the css into a php file.

Comment: Yep, it's true, but the question was about running php in css files. Obviously you can use .php files to provide dynamic CSS, but that is the different question.

Comment: indeed. I just felt it was worth mentioning in case the OP wasn't aware of this. Since the files end up looking more or less the same, it's a low-cost decision with potentially expensive ramifications down the line.

Answer (score 0):

If you give your CSS file a `.php` extension (e.g. `style.php`) you can include PHP code in it. You may also want to send a CSS MIME type in the header, e.g.:

```
header( 'Content-Type: text/css' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing the thing wrong way with a wrong syntax.

```
$hello= "'img/example.jpg'";
<style>p{background: url(<?php echo $hello;?>)};</style>
```

You are missing the quotes here.